# Pedagogical derivation of different PDFs

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, references

When I see the equations of a t distribution, or a Gamma, or a Chi squared I feel sometimes puzzled and ask to myself: how did they arrive to such not immediate intuitive equation?

I've seen derivations of the t distribution or some others here and there, but I would like to know if there's a book/article where it's shown how to deduce the PDFs of many important distributions, beginning perhaps with the binomial or the normal.